# Showing multiple variable in laravel select box

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

I am new to `laravel`. I want to create a select box in laravel form in which I want to show `first name and last name` in options. my controller is :

```
 $clients = Client::pluck('first_name','id')->toArray();
 $clients2 = Client::pluck('last_name','id')->toArray();
 view()->share('clients', $clients);
 view()->share('clients2', $clients2);
```

Here is my view file

```
 {!! Form::select('client_id', [''=>'--Select Client--']+$clients+ $clients2, null, ['id'=>'client_id', 'class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}
```

When I am executing this code then it is showing only `first_name`. How can I show the `last_name` also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Raw Expressions (DB::raw)` to achieve this :

```
$clients = Client::select(
           DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name"), 'id')
           ->pluck('name', 'id');
```

For more information : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: In this query I am getting issue, if any row doesnt have last_name then it is returning blank

Answer (score 1):

This may can help you:

```
    $clients = Client::select([
        DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name'),
        'id'
    ])
    ->pluck('full_name','id');
```

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it,

```
View::share('selectDestination', Posts::where('post_type','=','destination')->pluck("post_title","id")->all());
//pluck("post_title","id") That's you Option KEY and VALUE
```

in blade

```
{!! Form::select('destination',[''=>'--- Select Destination ---']+$selectDestination,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```